# opposite of jQuery find() that isn't not()?

Tags: jquery

Given the following HTML, what jQuery selector would select the last 'blah blah' `span` but not the first?

```
<div class='d1'>
  <span>
    <a>blee
      <span> <!-- don't select this span -->
        <span>blah</span> blah
      </span>
    </a>
  </span>
</div>

<br/>

<div class='d1'>
  <span>
    <a>blee
      <span> <!-- select this span -->
        blah blah
      </span>
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

I've tried variations using not() but can't figure it out. It seems like what I need is a selector that finds the first span, but then excludes it if it contains another span. Something like:

```
$('.d1 span a span').not(':has("span")')
```

but that doesn't do it.  What am I missing?

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution, or one for this specific markup? i.e will you have other `.d1` elements, or is this it?

Comment: general. there could be 10s or hundreds of groups like d1 above, but the above illustrates the base need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, all you're missing is a child combinator:

```
$('.d1 span a > span').not(':has("span")')
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2CLps/).

The reason you need this is that `.d1 span a span` will match *both* `span` descendants of the `a` element in the first `.d1` element. The `.not()` call will exclude the outer one, but the inner one will still be part of the matched set. By adding the child combinator, only the outer `span` is selected, and then removed by the call to `.not()`.

Comment: i'm selecting this one because it explains my need for the child selector.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want this selector:

`$('div.d1 span:last')`

Fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/aWCsT/

Answer (score 1):

Select only the child `span`s of that `a`:

```
$('.d1 span a > span:not(:has(span))')
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/eSDrK/1/**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.dl:last span:not(:has(*))')
```

Answer (score 0):

**[demo jsbin](http://jsbin.com/awoset/1/edit)**

```
$('a>span:not(:first)')
```